# Returning custom class from DAL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-objects

I have an object with following attributes

```
Books
----------
ID , Name
```

Now, I want to return an object for a gridview in presentation layer which has a lot more attributes then the original object

```
Gridview Object
--------------- 
ID, Name, Quantity, Location, ISBNNO, LastIssued
```

I don't have any business object composed of these attributes currently & I don't want to create it just for the sake of a gridview.

> How do I create & return custom
>   objects like these on the fly ? I am
>   new to DTO's. Can someone give me an
>   example to return a DTO inside my DAL
>   ?

Thanks,
Damien.

Comment: When you don't want to create objects for your application what are are you then creating objects for at all?

Comment: Sorry I meant, creating a business object file. Each of my business objects are inside a separate cs file.

Comment: Yes, each class should be inside it's own code file. Please don't get me wrong, but where is the problem to create a class inside it's own code file? I'm quite a bit confused I think.

Comment: Sorry PVitt, problem is that I am ending up with a lot of separate class files for each gridview. In my case, 150 of them.So I thought that maybe there was some way to put them inside a single class file or just create and return one object from DAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want to mess with your database objects, create a decorator for it

```
public class myGVObject
{
    public Book { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string ISBNNO { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastIssued { get; set; }
}
```

and in your gridView use:

```
<asp:Label id="lblBookId" text="<%# Eval("Book.ID") %>" />
<asp:Label id="lblLastIssue" text="<%# Eval("LastIssued") %>" />
```

Comment: Thanks balezandre. You are right. Is it good to create a separate decorator object or inherit some attributes from the previous class ?

Answer (score 1):

this what I found on google. Is it helping ?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/datatransferobject.aspx

http://aspalliance.com/1215

I think you could extend your book class or inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

How about you *project* your object out of a Linq query on the fly?

```
var result = from record in datastore
             select new
             {
                 ID = record.ID,
                 Name = record.Name,
                 Quantity = record.Quantity,
                 Location = record.Location,
                 ISBNNO = record.ISBN,
                 LastIssued = record.LastIssued
             };
GridView1.DataSource = result;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi, that seems to be a nice option but I'm using the grid on multiple pages so I would go with the decorator object.